# Split From Right to Left

Tags: excel, vba, split

my code so far has worked for split

How can I split it from right to left?

```
Sub try()
Dim size As String
Dim ResultSize() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim MaxSize As Integer

size = "36;37;38;39"
ResultSize = Split(size, ";")
MaxSize = UBound(ResultSize)

For i = 0 To MaxSize
  Debug.Print ResultSize(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Or do you just need to loop the array backwards: `For i = MaxSize to 0 Step -1`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may try it like this

```
Sub try()
Dim size As String
Dim ResultSize() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim MaxSize As Integer

size = "36;37;38;39"
ResultSize = Split(size, ";")
MaxSize = UBound(ResultSize)

For i = MaxSize to 0 Step -1
  Debug.Print ResultSize(i)
Next i

End Sub
```